# Using a lookup table will result in many foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, lookup-tables

I am looking for more educated opinions on how best to use a lookup table in a SQL Server database.

The rough explanation is that I have a Results table in which ratings are assigned to a number of fields. Then I have a lookup table for these ratings like this:

```
RatingCode   RatingName
1            Poor 
2            OK
3            Satisfactory
```

etc.
The results table has about 50 columns which will contain a rating code.

Should each of these 50 columns be a foreign key? Is this way too many foreign keys and will it hinder performance? Are there any other ways I can achieve this?

Comment: Any foreign key has an impact on performance during inserts and updates. The impact is extremely minimal and is a cost of RI. I would question a table that needs to have 50 ratings all pointing to the same table as a foreign key. That sounds like there are likely some design challenges in general.

Comment: Is it likely to add more columns? If so, probably you would like to make those columns as rows and pivot them in the application

Comment: The correct answer to this question depends entirely on what those 50 columns are and why there are so many of them.  That said, it is very likely that thos 50 columns are a repeating column in disguise that should be re-normalized into a child and type tables

Comment: You don't have a problem. If this is a lookup table, and the sample data shows that it is, the foreign keys will be in other tables referring back to this one. You will not have 50 foreign keys in one table, but one foreign key in each entity table that takes a rating.

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately sounds like a poorly designed table.

Just to clarify, you have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(KeyColumn, ThingWithRatingCode1, ThingWithRatingCode2 ..., ThingWithRatingCode50)
```

This is an example of a denormalised table. This would be much better structured as a normalised table:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(KeyColumn, ThingToBeRated, RatingCode)
```

Rather than one record with 50 columns, you would have 50 records per KeyColumn. Therefore you only have the one foreign key (from the RatingCode column in SomeTable to your lookup table).

For further explanations of this just Google "3rd normal form" or "normalisation". I would suggest normalisation is almost always a minimum best practice when designing databases and tables.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Regards,

Ash